# How much time to initialize an array to 0?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, time-complexity

I am confused whether
`int arr[n]={0}` takes constant time i.e. O(1), or O(n)?

Comment: It depends. Assuming this is C, you need to know what the storage duration of the variable is. (Or maybe this is some other language? You didn't say.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I am talking about C, but I don't know what you mean by storage duration

Comment: In general, can initialisation of array be done in constant time? It is part of an algorithm where I have to make a constant sized array zero after every execution of a loop

Comment: It will always take at least `O(n)`, as the memory locations need to be written to. [That is of course assuming memory access is always `O(1)`, which is a reasonable assumption for the capabilities of today's technology]

Comment: Zero-initialization of objects of static storage duration (e.g., global variables) is typically done at compile time and therefore incur no runtime cost. Zeroing out an existing variable cannot be any faster than O(size of variable) because an algorithm cannot be faster than the size of its output. Note that `int arr[n]={0}` does not zero out an existing variable. It creates a new variable whose initial values are all zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should expect O(N) time, but there are caveats:

- It is O(1) if memory occupied by array is smaller than the word size. (it may be O(1) all the way to the cache line size on modern CPUs)
- It is O(N) if array fits within a single tier in the memory.
- It is complicated if array pushes through the tiers: There are multiple tiers on all modern computers (registers, L0 cache, L1 cache, L3 cache?, NUMA on multi-CPU machines, Virtual memory(mapping to swap), ...). If array can't fit in one - there will be a severe performance penalty.

CPU cache architecture impacts the time needed to zero out memory quite severely. In practice calling it O(N) is somewhat misleading given that going from 100 to 101 may increase time 10x if it falls on a cache boundary (line or whole). It may be even more dramatic if swapping is involved. Beware of the tiered memory model...

Answer (score 1):

Generally initialization to zero of non-static storage is linear in the size of the storage. If you are reusing the array, it will need to be zero'ed each time. There are computer architectures that try to make this free via maintaining bit masks on pages or cache lines and returning zeroes at some point in the cache fill or load unit machinery. These are somewhat rare, but the effect can often be replicated in software if performance is paramount.

Arguably zeroed static storage is free but in practice the pages to back it up will be faulted in and there will be some cost to zero them on most architectures.

(One can end up in situations where the cost of the faults to provide zero filled pages is quite noticeable. E.g. repeated malloc/free of blocks bigger than some threshold can result in the address space backing the allocation being returned to the OS at each deallocation. The OS then has to zero it for security reasons even though malloc isn't guaranteed to return zero filled storage. Worse case the program then writes zeroes into the same block after it is returned from malloc so it ends up being twice the cost.)

For cases where large arrays of mostly zeroes will be accessed in a sparse fashion, the zero fill on demand behavior mentioned above can reduce the cost to linear in the number of pages actually used, not the total size. Arranging to do this usually requires using mmap or similar directly, not just allocating an array in C and zero initializing it.